# Would you use Brewing Sugar long past use by date? (3.5 years!)

Tags: beer, sugar

Having a sort out I've found a bag of brewing sugar that went out of date in August 2016! Curious, been stored in the dry, the bag s in tact and feels fine, I know very inexpensive to buy but waste not want not, thought about using it in a 1.8 kg can kit, would it be safe do you think or spoil the brew?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes, it's fine to use. It's only sugar. What can go bad? Unless it's obviously moldy and nasty, go for it.

Answer (score 4):

As Robert mentionned, it is still sugar even after 5 years!  I usually disolve it in boiling water to kill any bacteria, before adding to a wort (after cooling a bit).

Almost no chances of spoiling the brew when added this way.

Answer (score 1):

I've used brewing sugar that was ten years old. Hard as a brick (due to being packaged in plastic that was sufficiently permeable to water vapour) but in the fermenter it dissolved quickly and the yeast climbed into it without any problem. So go for it!